# Referring from a sub branch of the main module

Tags: git, go

I have a few changes that I have completed on a separate branch other than the main or master in the main app.

But now I need to refer a few modules from that particular branch (I too am building from it's local copy) to be used by the same branch, and currently I am getting the following error.

```
  go get -d github.com/orgname/reponame@feature/branch
go: package github.com/orgname/reponame is in the main module, so can't request version feature/branch
```

I did import another module from another private branch and that step in the process is now getting succeeded.

Is there any way to fix this, or is it must to proceed with the main branch

Anything that I am missing specific to Go?

Comment: You already got, and are building, the main module (`package main`, and some files that go with that). Now you're telling the Go compiler that it should stop compiling *this* code and go fetch some *other* files instead (thus replacing this entire `main` module with a different one), but it's too late, it's already compiling this code. Don't do that.

Comment: @torek thank you for your response. It would be because of the lack of understanding from my end on this matter. So the scenario is the new feature is there as a new branch, but the new modules are there as well. But need to refer these on the same branch, is there any alternative or changes that you can suggest to follow

Comment: If they're all part of the same module, update all the files and commit (adding to the feature branch or creating a new branch). Then build from there.